# How to know if all images are added dynamically loaded? javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, document-ready

My problem is not so simple because I dynamically add images after that document is ready as when these images are all loaded?

Comment: At least post the code that is adding the images !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onload` function to check that your image is loaded or not.

```
var image = document.getElementById("yourImage");
image.onload = function (){
//do stuff when your image is loaded
}
```